# Calling a python script from a Java jar file

Tags: java, python, pywin32

I am working on a project using Java and Python using Java for the GUI and Python for the backend. The Java program calls a Python script when a button is pressed using the following code:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
String pyScript = "resources/script.py";
String scriptPath = getClass().getResource(pyScript).toExternalForm();
// Strip "file/" from path
scriptPath = scriptPath.substring(scriptPath.indexOf("/") + 1);
Process p = r.exec("python " + scriptPath)
```

The python script is located in a folder called resources in the src folder of the Java project. This code works when I run my program in my IDE (IntelliJ) however when I create a .jar file and attempt to run the script nothing occurs. I can confirm that the program does still find the script within the .jar file.
How can I get the script to run?

Comment: Insert `System.out.println("Scriptpath: "+scriptPath);`before `r.exec(...)`. Maybe this gives you a hint

Comment: @JimHawkins I added a JOptionDialog to display that when I run the jar and it located the python script.

Comment: You can move the script out of your src and place it outside. If its part of src, it is bundled inside the jar which itself is a compact file. An Alrernate way is to dynamically create your script.py at runtime , execute it and delete the .py file

Comment: @AdityaPoorna Thanks that works.

Comment: @LionelPereira Please mark this resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution, we run the script if the file exists. The script could be on a full or relative path. The script is not in the jar file.

> TestPython.java

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestPython {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("I will run a Python script!");
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String pyScript = "py/test.py";

        File f = new File(pyScript);
        if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                Process p = r.exec("python " + pyScript);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in .readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                System.out.println("Python script ran!!");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Something bad happened!!");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unexistent file!" + pyScript);
        }
    }
}
```

> py/test.py

```
print("I'm a Python script!!!")
```

> **Output:**
>
> I will run a Python script!
>
> I'm a Python script!!!
>
> Python script ran!!